# Wordpress using add_filter and array_map

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, array-map, add-filter

I'm trying to modify a filter defined in a Wordpress/Woocommerce plugin. The filter is defined in the plugin as follows:

```
$product_objects = apply_filters('list_products_objects', array_map('wc_get_product', $ids));
```

$ids is an array of product_ids

```
$ids = array();
```

This code doesn't get executed

```
add_filter('remove_product_ids', 'list_products_objects', 10, 2 );
function remove_product_ids($product_ids) {
    $new_product_ids = array();
    if ( is_array($product_ids) ) {
        if ( !empty ($product_ids) ) {
            foreach( $product_ids as $key => $product_id ) {
                if ( in_array( get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' ), array( 'mugs','tshirts' ) ) ) { //Add the slug name here to include
                    $new_product_ids[] = $product_id;
                }
            }
            $product_ids = $new_product_ids;
        }
    }
    return $product_ids;
}
```

and this throws a PHP parse error

```
function remove_product_ids(array_map('wc_get_product', $product_ids)) {
```

have searched for answers on the web but wasn't able to find a comparable problem. What could be a solution to make this filter run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter receives an array of product objects, so the callback needs to expect that, and not an array of IDs. The `array_map()` function applies a function to every item in the array, and then saves that result back to the array. So in this case, `array_map()` takes an ID, gets the product for that ID, and saves it back into the array. Also, the filter name does not match.

Untested:

```php
add_filter( 'list_products_objects', static function ( $products ) {
    if ( empty( $products ) || ! is_array( $products ) ) {
        return $products;
    }

    // Remove any empty entries.
    $products = array_filter( $products );

    $filtered_products = array();

    foreach ( $products as $product ) {
        if ( ! has_term( array( 'mugs', 'tshirts' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $filtered_products = $product;
    }

    return $filtered_products;
} );
```

Comment: Caleb, your explanation seems logical. I'm getting another error though. ```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, WC_Product_Simple given in /var/www/wp-content-mount/plugins/...```

Comment: There's no `count()` call in my answer, so that error is likely separate. Please post a new question with the necessary details.

Comment: That's right, accepting your answer with a minor correction.

if ( ! has_term( array( 'mugs', 'tshirts' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {

Comment: I don't see the correction?

Comment: I've not been able to edit your answer as 'There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.' Will try again later. The only change is an ending ). Thanks Caleb for the great explanation.

Comment: Nevermind, the edit is in place from LoicTheAztec. Thanks for that.